# Amazon EC2 instance local data sharing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

Can EC2 local data shared like s3?

for example I have some text file in my EC2 instance home directory ex: home\mydata.txt 
I want to share mydata.txt as public url. I Know it can be by copying to s3, but want to check this option as well.

something like : https://ec2-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/mydata.txt

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can, as long as you are running a webserver on your instance and the webserver is configured to allow it to serve the file types you want to serve.

Depending on what you are trying to do, S3 may in fact be the better option, but it certainly is posssible and common to do what you are asking.